# difference in classes generated for a wsdl file in .net and java

Tags: webservices-client

i am trying to develop a client application (both in java and .net) using a wsdl file.
The problem scenario is that:
in .net the classes generated by adding wsdl is different to the classes generated by adding same wsdl file in java.
here the difference is that in java some classes are missing that are present in .net.
also for some class in .net the class variable is generated while in java these class members are missing for the same class.

so, please let me know why this type of different behavior is shown for the same wsdl file in .net and java.

Comment: .net and java are different programming languages, so of course the generated classes are different. If you post some extracts of the WSDL and the generated sources with the bits you feel are missing maybe people can help.

Comment: ya i agree to you. But the question is that why in the class generated in .net from wsdl has some class variable while in java it is not from the same wsdl.